# Web performance test in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

I know I can perform a web performance test using Visual Studio. However the results seem to only show the page load times.

Am I able to drill down to the code level to see which offending code is causing a slow down?

Comment: Sound like job for New Relic Tool.

Answer (score 1):

My answer below is from an end-user test perspective. If you have access to the application code, you can clearly debug performance via logs, utilization measurements, etc.

I suggest using a web profiler to analyze your network traffic. You can do this while generating load via your Visual Studio tests, or any other Web automation framework (JMeter, etc.).

There are many options, but you can use Chrome's developer tools right out of the box (CTRL-SHIFT-I).

For resource profiling: Select the Network tab, open the page(s) in question, and you'll see a nice timeline of all of the traffic and resources.

For time allocation: Select Timeline tab, select all of the capture options, open the page(s) in question, and you'll see a nice breakdown of time spent loading, scripting, rendering, etc.